# ElasticSearch: Querying a field that's an array of objects

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch

I've got data indexed using ElasticSearch, and I'm having trouble querying a particular field. A snippet of the JSON is as follows:

```
 {
 "_index": "indexName",
 "_type": "type",
 "_id": "00001",
 "color": "red",
 "place": "london",
 "person": [
      {
           "name": "john",
           "friends": [
               "mary",
               "jane"
           ]
      }
      {
           "name": "jack",
           "friends": [
               "lisa",
               "alex"
           ]
      }

 ]
 }
```

I need to query the index and pick out all records where one of the `name`s inside `person` is "john".

I'm using `Client.Search` to do this, and I've had no trouble querying the fields that aren't nested (like `color`) by using:

```
 var searchResults = client.Search<People>(s => s
            .Index("indexName")
            .Type("type")
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(
                        x => x.Match(m => m.OnField(p => p.color).Query("red")),
                        x => x.Match(m => m.OnField(p => p.place).Query("london"))))));
```

I've got `People` defined as follows:

```
public class People
{
    public string color {get; set; }
    public string place {get; set; }
    public List<Person> person {get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public string name {get; set; }
    // "friends" isn't here as I don't pull data from it
}
```

I'm unsure as to how to query on `name` as it's "inside" `people` - any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long while, I finally figured out that my data wasn't actually indexed as nested in the first place, and so simply adding

```
.Term("person.name", "john")
```

to my query worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap query in `nested_query` to have access to nested fields.

```
{
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "person",
        "query" : {
             "match" : {"person.name" : "john"}
        }
    }
}
```

Exceprt from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html):

> The query is executed against the nested objects / docs as if they
>   were indexed as separate docs (they are, internally) and resulting in
>   the root parent doc (or parent nested mapping).

Basically internally nested fields are stored as separate documents nearby (so they are quick to fetch) the original document. By default elastic doesn't load them, so you need to explicitly tell him that you want to access it. You could say nested fields are lazy ;)

Sorry It's been a long time since I worked on .Net and Linq. Don't know the API. But you need to create something like that.

**Edit.**
From github [source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/4fcecae93dcf16a4ff7e110135da81eed409dda5/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Query/Singles/NestedQueryJson.cs) and your code I think you need to:

```
var s = new SearchDescriptor<People>()
                .Query(ff=>ff
                    .Nested(n=>n
                        .Path(f=>f.person[0])
                        .Query(q=>q.Term(f=>f.person[0].name,"john"))
                    )
                );
```

**Edit2.**
Did you try direct curl to server? Or try query in head plugin? Something like:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9202/indexName' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "person",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "person.name: john"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This works on my cluster (with changed column names).

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)
I've tried all sorts of variations of `x => x.Match(m => m.OnField(p => p.person.name).Query("john"))` and all I seem to get is errors. I suspect I'm missing something obvious but there seems to be a lack of documentation for Elastic in C#.

Comment: I browsed the source code, and I can see nested query here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/4fcecae93dcf16a4ff7e110135da81eed409dda5/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/QueryParsers/Queries/NestedQueryTests.cs

Comment: I did, although it seems a little convoluted doing `.Query(q => q.Nested(n => n.Query(p => p.onField("person.name").Query("john"))))`.

Comment: I was a little too early - it compiled but returned no results, which I know isn't right!

Comment: I think `onField` should be just `"person"`. Also it seems that you're using wrong nested. It should have path and score properties. The github link I sent you had those. There's also nested aggregation and it looks like you're using it instead of nested query.

Comment: Still no good. I've added in `.Path("person")` too which made no difference.

Comment: Thanks for all of the advice - everything that I try just returns no results.